# Why position:absolute; will enlarge the test div's height?

Tags: html, css

The div.test was set height auto,no fixed height.

```css
.test {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  it is a test info for my div .
</div>
```

Now to add a `position:absolute;` in css,all other css attribution remains unchanged.

```css
.test {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  it is a test info for my div .
</div>
```

The height of div.test was enlarged,why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first case the `position` of the div is `static`, so top/right/bottom/left properties do not apply. Once you change the position to `absolute`, those properties are now taken into account. It is specifically the `bottom` property that is causing the div to expand. Try removing `bottom: 0;` from your code and you'll see the div collapse back to it's content's height:

```css
.test { 
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">it is a test info for my div.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `max-height:` to ensure it doesn't enlarge bigger than your expectation.